# How to get parameters of different type from an ellipsis in C

Tags: c, parameters, ellipsis

I have a function which accepts variable number of argumets of different data types using ellipsis. I wanted to know is there any way by which I can get each of them. If not all, atleast separate a particular argument (either first or last parameter) from the rest and *va_list* from the remaining. 
Declaration goes like this :

```
    int foo (char *a , ...)
```

Usage :

```
    result = foo ("I'm a String",2,34.56,"one more String",2323232323);

    result = foo ("I'm another String",3,"again one more String",34.62,111111111);
```

So, here(usage 1) I want to remove parameter '2' from the va_list got and make another va_list with the rest. Function declaration is flexible, and can be changed accordingly.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can not be processed and there is no type information of the argument after following the first argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that variable argument functions must have a way to determine the types of the arguments in the ellipsis (`va_list`).  The `printf()` and `scanf()` families of functions have the format string to specify the types; the `open()` system call has an optional third argument but it is always an `int`; and the `execl()` function takes a list of arguments all of the same type, `char *`, terminated by a NULL pointer).

If you have a function:

```
void foo_tail(va_list args);
```

You can write your function `foo()` as:

```
int foo(char *a, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, a);
    int arg2 = va_arg(args, int);
    foo_tail(args);
    va_end(args);
    return arg2;
}
```

This achieves what the question asks for:

> remove parameter '2' from the `va_list` got and make another `va_list` with the rest.

Whether `foo_tail()` can work out what to do with the `va_list` it is given is a separate discussion; it is not clear how it would distinguish between the two calls shown in the question, but to handle both, that information would have to be made available somehow.  A variable list of mixed types as shown is very problematic.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `va_arg` the argument you get is actually removed from the `va_list`. So the rest of the arguments are already in your `va_list`.

However, you can *not*, say, get an arbitrary argument from the list. They have to be taken in order. You also *must* know the actual types of the arguments you're getting.